# WPF - IntegerUpDown - Changing the spinner button color

Tags: wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit, integerupdown

I am using the Extended WPF Toolkit's IntegerUpDown. Is there anyway the spin button's color can be change.

[IntegerUpDown Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUhWS.jpg)

Comment: Changing the arrow color in WPF Toolkit NumericUpDown control talk about arrow. What I try to achieve was the button itself.

Comment: You said "Is there anyway the spin button's color can be change." So I thought you want to change the Color for the Up and Down Button like the duplicated Question. And your Screenshot marks the Up and Down Button too

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. From the previous post, the arrow in the button was change (result obtain from the post, I do try to it but it seem my end showing error). What I intent to do was changing the button itself so that from naked eye, the textbox and the spinbutton was separated

Comment: Sorry but now I really didn't know what you want to achieve

Comment: I do update the attached picture. Hope it was clear to you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `Background` (Inherited from `System.Windows.Controls.Control`) property of the spin button to change its color like normal controls.

See [Extended WPF Toolkit documentation](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ButtonSpinner_members.html).